# Como comparar índices de dois objetos e retornar o que está diferente?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Gostaria de comparar esses dois objetos e retornar o índice que está diferente.

Nesse caso é para retornar o 4 do segundo objeto (sempre será diferente no segundo).

```
var arr = {
   1 : 'Corsa',
   2 : 'Ka',
   3 : 'Pálio'
};

var foo = {
   1 : 'Corsa',
   2 : 'Ka',
   3 : 'Pálio',
   4 : 'Jeep'
};
```

Como faço isso em JavaScript ou usando jQuery ?

Comment: E se houver mais, se houver o 5 queres os dois (4 e 5) ou só o 5?

Comment: Sempre será 1 diferente.

Comment: Ha só um, ok percebi

Comment: E a ordem será sempre a mesma, valores iguais terão sempre o mesmo índice ou se tiver ordem diferente também retornar?

Comment: Na verdade ele vai vir em ordem alfabética.

Comment: Removi a resposta, pq não dá pra eu arrumar agora. Mas fiquem a vontade pra postar algo mais legal. Em principio a lógica é a mesma, iterar uma e ver se tem na outra, e acumular os resultados quando não achar. @Moshmage grato pelo aviso. Anderson, a duvida que vc tinha posto na resposta é pertinente.

Comment: @Bacco eu entendi sua lógica. Até porquê array não é tão diferente de se tratar com relação ao objeto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para objetos, você pode fazer da seguinte forma.:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototype, "except", {
  enumerable: false,
  value: function (outro)  {
    var keysB = Object.keys(outro);
    return Object.keys(this).reduce(function (resultado, key) {
      if (keysB.indexOf(key) == -1)
        resultado[key] = this[key];
      return resultado;
    }.bind(this), {});
  }
});

var foo = {
  1 : 'Corsa',
  2 : 'Ka',
  3 : 'Pálio'
};

var bar = {
  1 : 'Corsa',
  2 : 'Ka',
  3 : 'Pálio',
  4 : 'Jeep'
};

console.log(bar.except(foo));
```

Comment: +1, acho que tá bem legivel.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma é converter o objeto em *string* e salvar em um array. Nesse caso, mesmo que o tamanho dos objetos sejam incertos, no caso do primeiro ser maior do que o segundo, vai funcionar.

```js
var arr = {
  1: 'Corsa',
  2: 'Ka',
  3: 'Pálio'
};

var foo = {
  1: 'Corsa',
  2: 'Ka',
  3: 'Pálio',
  4: 'Jeep'  
};

var obj1 = JSON.stringify(arr).replace(/{|}/g, '').split(",");
var obj2 = JSON.stringify(foo).replace(/{|}/g, '').split(",");
var maior = Math.max(obj1.length, obj2.length);

for (var i = 0; i < maior; i++) {
  if (obj1.length > obj2.length) {
    if (obj1[i] != obj2[i]) {
      console.log("índice diferente: " + obj1[i].split(":")[0] + " entre os objs");
      break;
    }
  } else {
    if (obj2[i] != obj1[i]) {
      console.log("índice diferente: " + obj2[i].split(":")[0] + " entre os objs");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Precisas de saber qual o Objeto com mais chaves, e depois iterar até encontrar uma chave que o outro não tenha. Podes fazer isso assim:

```
function comparar(a, b) {
    var axb = Object.keys(a).length > Object.keys(b);
    var mairObjeto = axb ? a : b;
    var menorObjeto = axb ? b : a;

    for (var i in mairObjeto) {
        if (!menorObjeto.hasOwnProperty(i)) return i
    }
}
```

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
var foo = {
    1: 'Corsa',
    2: 'Ka',
    3: 'Pálio'
};

var bar = {
    1: 'Corsa',
    2: 'Ka',
    3: 'Pálio',
    4: 'Jeep'
};

function comparar(a, b) {
    var axb = Object.keys(a).length > Object.keys(b);
    var mairObjeto = axb ? a : b;
    var menorObjeto = axb ? b : a;

    for (var i in mairObjeto) {
        if (!menorObjeto.hasOwnProperty(i)) return i
    }
}

console.log(comparar(foo, bar));
```